# Imprimir una columna de números en python

Tags: python, lista

El código es muy sencillo, el problema mas bien es "estético".

Resulta que si imprimo por pantalla columnas de números positivos o negativos, se imprimen de forma desalineada, ¿Hay alguna manera de corregir ese problema?

```
x = [[1,1154,5412],[2,4527,5698],[3,2879,-5687],[4,5547,-5698],[5,7658,6589],
     [6,9651,-4565],[7,-4156,-6548],[8,-2264,6568],[9,-1657,6597],[10,-1643,5481]]

for i in range(len(x)):

    print(str(x[i][0]).zfill(2),x[i][1],x[i][2])
```

Se me imprimen así:

```
01 1154 5412
02 4527 5698
03 2879 -5687
04 5547 -5698
05 7658 6589
06 9651 -4565
07 -4156 -6548
08 -2264 6568
09 -1657 6597
10 -1643 5481
```

Busco que se me impriman así:

```
01  1154  5412
02  4527  5698
03  2879 -5687
04  5547 -5698
05  7658  6589
06  9651 -4565
07 -4156 -6548
08 -2264  6568
09 -1657  6597
10 -1643  5481
```

He ahí la diferencia, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el formateo en las cadenas

```py
x = [[1,1154,5412],[2,4527,5698],[3,2879,-5687],[4,5547,-5698],[5,7658,6589],
     [6,9651,-4565],[7,-4156,-6548],[8,-2264,6568],[9,-1657,6597],[10,-1643,5481]]

for i in x:
    print(f"{i[0]:02} {i[1]:>5} {i[2]:>5}")
```

Comment: Muy práctico amigo, muchas gracias.